# Can I return List<MyModel> to my View from my Controller? (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can I return List to my View from my Controller, or do I need to wrap my List in another class, just for the sake of returning only a class?

If this is possible, how do I iterate over the list? I'm trying this (Razor), but Visual Studio isn't happy about it:

```
@model List<QueueItem>
.
.
.
@foreach (item in @Model)
```

Comment: Yes you can do it, but until you post the actual exception, it will be mostly guessing in the dark how to solve your problem.

Comment: "Cannot resolve the symbol item."

Comment: Looks like the problem is in you `foreach` line, try `@foreach (var item in @Model)`.

Comment: D'oh! Total brain fart! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way, but I never return my domain objects directly to a view. Normally I have a view model for a view containing only the fields that I need on that view.

Given your scenario I would have this list in a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<QueueItem> QueueItems { get; set; }
}
```

In your action method you will populate these items from a service/repository call and then this view model would be returned to the view:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
          QueueItems = queueItemRepository.GetAllQueueItems()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

In your view you would loop through the items and do what needs to be done:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.QueueItems)
{
}
```

I hope this helps.